# Devise controllers "uninitialized constant Api::V1::RegistrationsController" in Rails API only

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Im creating a rails api, I want the resources to be under `/api/v1/` route, including the registration and authentication.

I have created the following routes which gives me the desired routes for Devise:

`config/routes.rb`

```
namespace :api, defaults: { format: :json } do
  namespace :v1 do
    devise_for :users, as: 'api'
  end
end
```

It provides:

```
                      Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                      Controller#Action
          new_api_user_session GET    /api/v1/users/sign_in(.:format)  api/v1/sessions#new {:format=>:json}
              api_user_session POST   /api/v1/users/sign_in(.:format)  api/v1/sessions#create {:format=>:json}
      destroy_api_user_session DELETE /api/v1/users/sign_out(.:format) api/v1/sessions#destroy {:format=>:json}
  cancel_api_user_registration GET    /api/v1/users/cancel(.:format)   api/v1/registrations#cancel {:format=>:json}
     new_api_user_registration GET    /api/v1/users/sign_up(.:format)  api/v1/registrations#new {:format=>:json}
    edit_api_user_registration GET    /api/v1/users/edit(.:format)     api/v1/registrations#edit {:format=>:json}
         api_user_registration PATCH  /api/v1/users(.:format)          api/v1/registrations#update {:format=>:json}
                               PUT    /api/v1/users(.:format)          api/v1/registrations#update {:format=>:json}
                               DELETE /api/v1/users(.:format)          api/v1/registrations#destroy {:format=>:json}
                               POST   /api/v1/users(.:format)          api/v1/registrations#create {:format=>:json}
```

However, when I try to register a user I get the following error

```
ActionController::RoutingError:
   uninitialized constant Api::V1::RegistrationsController
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order to keep the resources under `/api/v1/` path and still be able to use devise's default controllers, the routes need to be fixed.

Instead of using `namespace`, use `scope`.

```
scope :api, defaults: { format: :json } do
  scope :v1 do
    devise_for :users
  end
end
```

This way you dont even have to use the `as: 'api'` to identify your resource

```
                  Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                      Controller#Action
        new_user_session GET    /api/v1/users/sign_in(.:format)  devise/sessions#new {:format=>:json}
            user_session POST   /api/v1/users/sign_in(.:format)  devise/sessions#create {:format=>:json}
    destroy_user_session DELETE /api/v1/users/sign_out(.:format) devise/sessions#destroy {:format=>:json}
cancel_user_registration GET    /api/v1/users/cancel(.:format)   devise/registrations#cancel {:format=>:json}
   new_user_registration GET    /api/v1/users/sign_up(.:format)  devise/registrations#new {:format=>:json}
  edit_user_registration GET    /api/v1/users/edit(.:format)     devise/registrations#edit {:format=>:json}
       user_registration PATCH  /api/v1/users(.:format)          devise/registrations#update {:format=>:json}
                         PUT    /api/v1/users(.:format)          devise/registrations#update {:format=>:json}
                         DELETE /api/v1/users(.:format)          devise/registrations#destroy {:format=>:json}
                         POST   /api/v1/users(.:format)          devise/registrations#create {:format=>:json}
```